# Does "Seize the Spotlight" target?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Seize the Spotlight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=false&multiverseid=562537) from the new Streets of Capenna EDH deck lets my opponents choose fame or fortune when cast.

For each opponent who chose fortune I draw a card and create a treasure token.

For each opponent who chose fame I

> gain control of a creature that player controls until end of turn.

Since there's no mentioning of the word "target", I should be able to choose any creature controlled by that opponent, even ones with hexproof or shroud. Am I correct?

I was wondering about this, since usually spells of this kind include the word "target" and thus this new spell feels a bit overpowered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Seize the Spotlight does not target, as its text does not use the word "target"**

You can indeed choose any creature you want, including creatures with shroud and/or hexproof.

> 115.1a An instant or sorcery spell is targeted if its spell ability identifies something it will affect by using the phrase “target [something],” where the “something” is a phrase that describes an object and/or player.  [..]